# Accessing Images from Xcode "Folder Reference" in Interface Builder UIImageView

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, uiimageview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Interface Builder - Moved resources to sub-directory, now IB can't see them!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812731/iphone-interface-builder-moved-resources-to-sub-directory-now-ib-cant-see-th)

There is a Folder Reference that contains my images in Xcode. I want to load an image from that image into an UIImageView *inside* of Xcode rather than programmatically, so I can visually design the interface.

Not only do the images in that folder not appear in the Image View->Image drop-down menu in Interface Builder, the images don't show up when I manually type in the path.

Comment: [Answer found here on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812731/iphone-interface-builder-moved-resources-to-sub-directory-now-ib-cant-see-the/1812847#1812847)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the images into the Resources folder in Xcode instead of your folder reference.  Also, make sure the images have been added to the target from which you want to be able to access the images.  To do this:

1. Select the image in the Groups & Files column in Xcode
2. Right-click on the image and select Get Info
3. In the Info window that comes up, select the Targets tab
4. Check the boxes next to the targets that you need to be able to access this file from

Comment: I've always done that before, I don't want to use that method anymore. The images are being added to the target because I am able to use them programmatically.