# how to get resource path using subpath Using NSBundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Have the folder structure like

```
*Resources/books/CD_en/icon/0.jpg;
*Resources/books/CD_en/icon/1.jpg;
*Resources/books/DD_en/icon/0.jpg;
*Resources/books/DD_en/icon/1.jpg;
```

how to get resource path from `NSBundle` using the subpath `'books/CD_en/icon/0.jpg'`

I tried using,

```
- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)subpath

[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"0.jpg" ofType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"books/CD_en/icon"];
```

but it returns `nil`.

Comment: I think yehnan has it -- your name should be 0 and not 0.jpg

Comment: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"0" ofType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"books/CD_en/icon"];

Wrongly typed... i did as above

Comment: I think the problem is related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401338/include-a-resource-directory-hierarchy-into-app-bundle

Answer (score 2):

I got it. Simply we need the add the folder structure 'books/...' to the app Resource folder. Which will display in blue color.

Then the existing code is running successfully.

Thanks to yehnan.

Answer (score 1):

i got same problem to retrive image from `Resource` folder. Adding image by following method solved my problem.

- Right click on project in xcode and select `Add Files to "project name"`.
- Select your image file from computer local disk.
- In the pop-up window make sure you select `Copy items into destination group's folder` and `Create Folder References for any added folders` and `Add to targets`.
- click `Add`.

Then with bellow code i can retrive my image.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"png"];
```