# How to Deal with Same named files in supporting files directory

Tags: ios, xcode, filesystems

Say for example In Xcode I make 3 folders in my supporting files older named "a" "b" and "c".

In each of these folders I have an xml file name "file.xml".

How can I use NSMainBundle to get paths to these 3 different xml files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get these files at runtime Xcode will copy them in the Copy Bundle Resource phase. This normally copies into the root of the bundle. To deal with directories see @CocoaFu's answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401338/include-a-resource-directory-hierarchy-into-app-bundle).

Then in the code

`NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]` will give you the main bundle

From this you look in directories using pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory: e.g.

```
NSString* path = [bundle pathForResource:@"file.xml" 
                                  ofType:nil 
                             inDirectory:@"a"];
```

The methods are given in [NSBundle class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) also see the [Bundle Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i)

Comment: do I need to add a copy files phase for each folder?