# Exclude specific files under a folder reference in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4, resources, hierarchy, app-bundle

I've added a resources directory as a folder reference to the app bundle according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401338/include-a-resource-directory-hierarchy-into-app-bundle). I'd like to exclude some of underlying files, since I don't need them in my app.

The "Delete" context menu item is disabled on every file below the root folder. If I add the files with "Create Groups", they are added flat, without any hierarchy.

Is it possible to remove specific files under a folder reference? Is there another way to add files and keep the hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name implies, it's a reference to the folder, not to the files.  The folder gets included in your bundle.  If you don't want some of the files in the bundle, you'll have to remove them from the folder.

Comment: Thanks, but can I somehow use the other option ("Create Groups") and still maintain the hierarchy, even manually?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a symbolic link to the folder, add a group that points to the link, and then remove references to any files unwanted in the group.

Comment: Hi, could you please expand this answer to show the specific steps needed to do this?