# swift ios and geing final grip on copy bundle resources

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am currenly converting an iOS project built in another tool to xcode/swift.

I currently have an xcode swift ios project with multiple targets defined (one for each customer)

For each customer I have a folder "customerxyzassets" that I have added to "target > build phases > copy bundle resources" using the process described here [Include a resource directory hierarchy into app bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401338/include-a-resource-directory-hierarchy-into-app-bundle)

This folder "customerxyzassets" contains subfolders with images and data files which the app is born with.

I would like to grab a path to this folder upon startup, so I can access load datafiles, images etc. from it.

However, the code I have found, e.g. *NSBundle.mainBundle*, seems to require speciel access to the files through the above. I would rather have raw file access to it. Am i missing something obvious?

Comment: The bundle can find the path for you

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean here by "special access" or "raw access." `NSBundle` just returns you paths or URLs so you can directly access the files using normal file APIs.

If you've created a directory structure, then you would generally use `pathForResource(_:ofType:inDirectory:)` to fetch the path to your specific file. Alternately, you can build a path using `NSBundle.resourcePath` and append your relative path using `stringByAppendingPathComponent`. The advantage of the `pathForResource` methods is that they handle localization for you, and this is preferred unless the resource should never be localized (which is rare).